# How to merge different pattern into single pattern in regex

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to merge below four pattern into single pattern using pipe(`|`), but not getting the required result.

Scenario:

- max 7 entry(alphabet and digits)
- should contain 4 and only 4 consecutive digits(mandatory)

Patterns:

```
([\d]{4}[a-zA-Z]{0,3})
[a-zA-Z]{0,1}[\d]{4}[a-zA-Z]{0,2}
[a-zA-Z]{0,2}[\d]{4}[a-zA-Z]{0,1}
[a-zA-Z]{0,3}[\d]{4})
```

Comment: You can achieve that with lookarounds - `^(?=[a-zA-Z]*\d{4})[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,7}$`. What is the regex flavor?

Comment: valid input:  abc1234;ab1234;1234;1234abd    Invalid input: 1a1234;12345;a1s1234

Comment: How are those 4 patterns work? In Java `String#matches()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z\d]{4,7}$)[a-zA-Z]*\d{4}[a-zA-Z]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vB0sX9/1)

If you are using the regex pattern in a method that anchors the pattern by default, the `^` and/or `$` might be redundant, but will still work.

The regex breakdown:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=[a-zA-Z\d]{4,7}$)` - the positive lookahead requiring the string to only consist of 4 to 7 letters or digits
- `[a-zA-Z]*\d{4}[a-zA-Z]* - the string should contain 4 digits (`\d{4}`) that can be preceded or followed with zero or more letters
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor..Its working for me. Can you help me to know the best resource for regex pattern? I know the basic only.It will be really helpful if you know about any resource having some detailed info.

Comment: I can only suggest doing all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean).